# Table image not showing, "Pop an autorelease pool" error

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios-simulator

I have a UITableView which uses the following code to display an image in a Table View cell:

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[color types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
 if ( image ) {
  cell.imageView.image = [image imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
 }
```

It works fine on the iPhone simulator, but when I try it on a real iPhone the iPhone doesn't show. Instead in the console in debugging mode, I get this error:

> attempt to pop an unknown autorelease
>   pool (0x851e00)

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please try commenting out the lines above and running the code again.  Do you still get the message?  I think you have some memory management issues in your app not necessarily related to the above.  Apparently, you can debug the message by putting a breakpoint on _CFAutoreleasePoolPop.

Comment: Alright have done so, and you're right they still appear. So that's another issue I'll look into. Any advice on how to fix this problem though?

Answer (score 0):

Check that image != nil. If it == nil then problem in that `[[color types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` code.
Generated file name must be equal real file name including extension, case and must not contain whitespaces.

Comment: Simple add after "UIImage *image = [U...." NSLog(@"Image %@", (image)?@"exist":@"not exist");

Comment: OK thanks - the result is "not exist" so I'm not sure what's going on here. In the simulator it does exist, but on the iPhone it doesn't!